# How to Process RGB Data from the CPU on an NVIDIA GPU and Visualize the Data with an OpenGL Texture

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

I'm hoping to create a simple computer vision library in C++/CUDA C++ that allows me to do the following:

- Grab some RGB data from the host memory. This data will come in a BGR byte array, 8 bits per channel per pixel.
- Process that data in a CUDA kernel.
- Write the output of that kernel back into some host memory.
- Render the output in an OpenGL texture for easy viewing.

These functions would go inside a class like so:

```cpp
class Processor{
public:
    setInput(const byte* data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight);
    void processData();
    GLuint getInputTexture();
    GLuint getOutputTexture();
    void writeOutputTo(byte* destination);
}
```

`setInput()` is going to be called with every frame of a video (hundreds or thousands of images of the same dimensions).

How can I write the Processor class so that `setInput()` can efficiently update an instance's internal CUDA array and `processData()` can synchronize the CUDA array with the OpenGL texture?

Below is my attempt at implementing such a class, contained in one CUDA C++ file along with a simple test.  (Requires [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/) and [GLAD](https://glad.dav1d.de/).) With this implementation, I can provide some input image data, run a CUDA kernel that produces an output image, and visualize both with OpenGL textures. But it's extremely inefficient because every time `setInput()` is called, two OpenGL textures and two CUDA surface objects need to be created. And if more than one image is processed, two OpenGL textures and two CUDA surface objects also have to be destroyed.

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <cudaGL.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#include <iostream>


/** Macro for checking if CUDA has problems */
#define cudaCheckError() { \
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError(); \
    if(err != cudaSuccess) { \
      printf("Cuda error: %s:%d: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err)); \
      exit(1); \
    } \
  }


/*Window dimensions*/
const int windowWidth = 1280, windowHeight = 720;
/*Window address*/
GLFWwindow* currentGLFWWindow = 0;


/**
 * A simple image processing kernel that copies the inverted data from the input surface to the output surface.
 */
__global__ void kernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t input, cudaSurfaceObject_t output, int width, int height) {

    //Get the pixel index
    unsigned int xPx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    unsigned int yPx = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;


    //Don't do any computation if this thread is outside of the surface bounds.
    if (xPx >= width || yPx >= height) return;

    //Copy the contents of input to output.
    uchar4 pixel = { 255,128,0,255 };
    //Read a pixel from the input. Disable to default to the flat orange color above
    surf2Dread<uchar4>(&pixel, input, xPx * sizeof(uchar4), yPx, cudaBoundaryModeClamp);

    //Invert the color
    pixel.x = ~pixel.x;
    pixel.y = ~pixel.y;
    pixel.z = ~pixel.z;

    //Write the new pixel color to the 
    surf2Dwrite(pixel, output, xPx * sizeof(uchar4), yPx);
}

class Processor {
public:
    void setInput( uint8_t* const data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight);
    void processData();
    GLuint getInputTexture();
    GLuint getOutputTexture();
    void writeOutputTo(uint8_t* destination);
private:
    /**
    * @brief True if the textures and surfaces are initialized.
    *
    * Prevents memory leaks
    */
    bool surfacesInitialized = false;
    /**
     * @brief The width and height of a texture/surface pair.
     *
     */
    struct ImgDim { int width, height; };
    /**
     * @brief Creates a CUDA surface object, CUDA resource, and OpenGL texture from some data.
     */
    void createTextureSurfacePair(const ImgDim& dimensions, uint8_t* const data, GLuint& textureOut, cudaGraphicsResource_t& graphicsResourceOut, cudaSurfaceObject_t& surfaceOut);
    /**
     * @brief Destroys every CUDA surface object, CUDA resource, and OpenGL texture created by this instance.
     */
    void destroyEverything();
    /**
     * @brief The dimensions of an image and its corresponding texture.
     *
     */
    ImgDim imageInputDimensions, imageOutputDimensions;
    /**
     * @brief A CUDA surface that can be read to, written from, or synchronized with a Mat or
     * OpenGL texture
     *
     */
    cudaSurfaceObject_t d_imageInputTexture = 0, d_imageOutputTexture = 0;
    /**
     * @brief A CUDA resource that's bound to an array in CUDA memory
     */
    cudaGraphicsResource_t d_imageInputGraphicsResource, d_imageOutputGraphicsResource;
    /**
     * @brief A renderable OpenGL texture that is synchronized with the CUDA data
     * @see d_imageInputTexture, d_imageOutputTexture
     */
    GLuint imageInputTexture = 0, imageOutputTexture = 0;
    /** Returns true if nothing can be rendered */
    bool empty() { return imageInputTexture == 0; }

};


void Processor::setInput(uint8_t* const data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
{


    //Same-size images don't need texture regeneration, so skip that.
    if (imageHeight == imageInputDimensions.height && imageWidth == imageInputDimensions.width) {


        /*
        Possible shortcut: we know the input is the same size as the texture and CUDA surface object.
        So instead of destroying the surface and texture, why not just overwrite them?

        That's what I try to do in the following block, but because "data" is BGR and the texture
        is RGBA, the channels get all messed up.
        */

        /*
        //Use the input surface's CUDAResourceDesc to gain access to the surface data array
        struct cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
        memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
        cudaGetSurfaceObjectResourceDesc(&resDesc, d_imageInputTexture);
        cudaCheckError();

        //Copy the data from the input array to the surface
        cudaMemcpyToArray(resDesc.res.array.array, 0, 0, input.data, imageInputDimensions.width * imageInputDimensions.height * 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaCheckError();

        //Set status flags
        surfacesInitialized = true;

        return;
        */
    }


    //Clear everything that originally existed in the texture/surface
    destroyEverything();

    //Get the size of the image and place it here.
    imageInputDimensions.width = imageWidth;
    imageInputDimensions.height = imageHeight;
    imageOutputDimensions.width = imageWidth;
    imageOutputDimensions.height = imageHeight;

    //Create the input surface/texture pair
    createTextureSurfacePair(imageInputDimensions, data, imageInputTexture, d_imageInputGraphicsResource, d_imageInputTexture);

    //Create the output surface/texture pair
    uint8_t* outData = new uint8_t[imageOutputDimensions.width * imageOutputDimensions.height * 3];
    createTextureSurfacePair(imageOutputDimensions, outData, imageOutputTexture, d_imageOutputGraphicsResource, d_imageOutputTexture);
    delete outData;

    //Set status flags
    surfacesInitialized = true;
}

void Processor::processData()
{
    const int threadsPerBlock = 128;

    //Call the algorithm

    //Set the number of blocks to call the kernel with.
    dim3 blocks((unsigned int)ceil((float)imageInputDimensions.width / threadsPerBlock), imageInputDimensions.height);
    kernel <<<blocks, threadsPerBlock >>> (d_imageInputTexture, d_imageOutputTexture, imageInputDimensions.width, imageInputDimensions.height);

    //Sync the surface with the texture
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckError();
}

GLuint Processor::getInputTexture()
{
    return imageInputTexture;
}

GLuint Processor::getOutputTexture()
{
    return imageOutputTexture;
}

void Processor::writeOutputTo(uint8_t* destination)
{
    //Haven't figured this out yet
}

void Processor::createTextureSurfacePair(const Processor::ImgDim& dimensions, uint8_t* const data, GLuint& textureOut, cudaGraphicsResource_t& graphicsResourceOut, cudaSurfaceObject_t& surfaceOut) {

    // Create the OpenGL texture that will be displayed with GLAD and GLFW
    glGenTextures(1, &textureOut);
    // Bind to our texture handle
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureOut);
    // Set texture interpolation methods for minification and magnification
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    // Set texture clamping method
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    // Create the texture and its attributes
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,     // Type of texture
        0,                // Pyramid level (for mip-mapping) - 0 is the top level
        GL_RGBA,          // Internal color format to convert to
        dimensions.width,            // Image width  i.e. 640 for Kinect in standard mode
        dimensions.height,           // Image height i.e. 480 for Kinect in standard mode
        0,                // Border width in pixels (can either be 1 or 0)
        GL_BGR,          // Input image format (i.e. GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, GL_BGR etc.)
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // Image data type.
        data);            // The actual image data itself
    //Note that the type of this texture is an RGBA UNSIGNED_BYTE type. When CUDA surfaces
    //are synchronized with OpenGL textures, the surfaces will be of the same type.
    //They won't know or care about their data types though, for they are all just byte arrays
    //at heart. So be careful to ensure that any CUDA kernel that handles a CUDA surface
    //uses it as an appropriate type. You will see that the update_surface kernel (defined 
    //above) treats each pixel as four unsigned bytes along the X-axis: one for red, green, blue,
    //and alpha respectively.

    //Create the CUDA array and texture reference
    cudaArray* bitmap_d;
    //Register the GL texture with the CUDA graphics library. A new cudaGraphicsResource is created, and its address is placed in cudaTextureID.
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1g80d12187ae7590807c7676697d9fe03d
    cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&graphicsResourceOut, textureOut, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone);
    cudaCheckError();
    //Map graphics resources for access by CUDA.
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1gad8fbe74d02adefb8e7efb4971ee6322
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &graphicsResourceOut, 0);
    cudaCheckError();
    //Get the location of the array of pixels that was mapped by the previous function and place that address in bitmap_d
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1g0dd6b5f024dfdcff5c28a08ef9958031
    cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&bitmap_d, graphicsResourceOut, 0, 0);
    cudaCheckError();
    //Create a CUDA resource descriptor. This is used to get and set attributes of CUDA resources.
    //This one will tell CUDA how we want the bitmap_surface to be configured.
    //Documentation for the struct: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaResourceDesc.html#structcudaResourceDesc
    struct cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
    //Clear it with 0s so that some flags aren't arbitrarily left at 1s
    memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
    //Set the resource type to be an array for convenient processing in the CUDA kernel.
    //List of resTypes: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g067b774c0e639817a00a972c8e2c203c
    resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    //Bind the new descriptor with the bitmap created earlier.
    resDesc.res.array.array = bitmap_d;
    //Create a new CUDA surface ID reference.
    //This is really just an unsigned long long.
    //Docuentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1gbe57cf2ccbe7f9d696f18808dd634c0a
    surfaceOut = 0;
    //Create the surface with the given description. That surface ID is placed in bitmap_surface.
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT_1g958899474ab2c5f40d233b524d6c5a01
    cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&surfaceOut, &resDesc);
    cudaCheckError();
}

void Processor::destroyEverything()
{
    if (surfacesInitialized) {

        //Input image CUDA surface
        cudaDestroySurfaceObject(d_imageInputTexture);
        cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &d_imageInputGraphicsResource);
        cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(d_imageInputGraphicsResource);
        d_imageInputTexture = 0;

        //Output image CUDA surface
        cudaDestroySurfaceObject(d_imageOutputTexture);
        cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &d_imageOutputGraphicsResource);
        cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(d_imageOutputGraphicsResource);
        d_imageOutputTexture = 0;

        //Input image GL texture
        glDeleteTextures(1, &imageInputTexture);
        imageInputTexture = 0;

        //Output image GL texture
        glDeleteTextures(1, &imageOutputTexture);
        imageOutputTexture = 0;

        surfacesInitialized = false;
    }
}


/** A way to initialize OpenGL with GLFW and GLAD */
void initGL() {

    // Setup window
    if (!glfwInit())
        return;

    // Decide GL+GLSL versions
#if __APPLE__
    // GL 3.2 + GLSL 150
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 150";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // Required on Mac
#else
    // GL 3.0 + GLSL 130
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 130";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // 3.0+ only
#endif

    // Create window with graphics context
    currentGLFWWindow = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Output image (OpenGL + GLFW)", NULL, NULL);
    if (currentGLFWWindow == NULL)
        return;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(currentGLFWWindow);
    glfwSwapInterval(3); // Enable vsync

    if (!gladLoadGL()) {
        // GLAD failed
        printf( "GLAD failed to initialize :(" );
        return;
    }

    //Change GL settings
    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); // use a screen size of WIDTH x HEIGHT

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);     // Make a simple 2D projection on the entire window
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);    // Set the matrix mode to object modeling

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the window
}

/** Renders the textures on the GLFW window and requests GLFW to update */
void showTextures(GLuint top, GLuint bottom) {
    // Clear color and depth buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // Operate on model-view matrix

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, top);
    /* Draw top quad */
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, windowHeight/2);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(windowWidth, 0);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    /* Draw top quad */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bottom);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, windowHeight / 2);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, windowHeight);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glfwSwapBuffers(currentGLFWWindow);
    glfwPollEvents();
}


int main() {
    initGL();

    int imageWidth = windowWidth;
    int imageHeight = windowHeight / 2;

    uint8_t* imageData = new uint8_t[imageWidth * imageHeight * 3];

    Processor p;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(currentGLFWWindow))
    {
        //Process the image here
        p.setInput(imageData, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        p.processData();
        showTextures(p.getInputTexture(), p.getOutputTexture());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am 99% certain you will have to copy into the OpenGL texture and then bind/unbind to CUDA. You can't use the CUDA host memory transfer to an OpenGL texture

Comment: `This code compiles without errors`  It's my suggestion that you provide a compilable example, even if it is not working.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes, I use it here: https://github.com/m516/CV-Sandbox/blob/master/src/09-OpenCV-Video-Template/algorithms/cuda_algorithm.cu

Comment: The request is essentially similar to the one I made on your last question, a [mcve], in the question itself.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for as well: a minimal reproducible example that allows me to efficiently process data from the CPU on the GPU and render it with OpenGL. I placed my code in the question to (1) prove that I have tried hard to find an answer on my own, (2) I did find a solution on my own, and (3) that my answer is extremely inefficient because it creates and destroys the OpenGL texture and CUDA surface. Perhaps I should reword the question

Comment: The reason there is a link to [mcve] is because there is more to what is being referred to than just the words "minimal reproducible example".  What I'm asking for is an example of something you tried that *isn't working*.  That is the impetus for your question, after all.  You state "I've tried the following..." then have some bullets.  Take the first bullet, make an example out of it, and put it in the question.  That example should be: 1.  Complete.  I should be able to copy, paste, compile, and run, and see the issue, without having to add or change anything.

Comment: 2. In the question itself, not via a link to somewhere.   3. hopefully, minimal.  This means stripped down to the minimum number of lines of code that still show the issue. However don't violate 1 or 2 in the process of making this example, as you work on item 3.  That's the request, and I believe its in-line with SO stated expectations for questions of this type.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Oh, I see. A small but complete example has been added in the latest edit

Comment: I fail to see why a (not accessible to anyone but you) movie file has to be part of an [MCVE]

Comment: @talonmies I don't either. The question has been updated to remove OpenCV from the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:  I can see at least 2 ways forward here, either convert your data to 4 byte pixels (somehow) and use `cudaMemcpy2DToArray`,  or allow the CUDA kernel to take in raw data (instead of using a surface as input).  I'll try to demonstrate both, although I don't wish to put in a large effort at polishing this, so really just demonstrating ideas.

This answer is working off the code you provided in [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63627239/4) which is not your latest.  However in the subsequent edits, mainly you seem to be just ripping out OpenCV, which I would normally applaud.  However, since I've worked off your edit that had OpenCV in it, I've elected to use an OpenCV "test case" of my own.

1. Using 4 byte-per-pixel data, and `cudaMemcpy2DToArray`:  This seems to adhere most closely to what you have demonstrated, albeit commented-out.  The idea is we will access the input data by copying it to the CUDA array (acquired from the interop mechanism) directly.  As you had previously pointed out, `cudaMemcpyToArray` is [deprecated](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cudamemcpytoarray-is-deprecated/71385), so we won't use that.  Furthermore, our data format (bytes per pixel) has to match what is in the array.  I think there are a number of ways to solve this, depending on your overall pipeline, but the approach I show here isn't efficient, it's just to demonstrate that the method is "workable".  If there is a way to use 4 byte per pixel data in your pipeline, however, you may be able to get rid of the "inefficiency" here.  To use this method, compile the code with the `-DUSE_1` switch.
2. Input of the data through the kernel.  We can skip the inefficiency of the first case by just allowing the kernel to do the 3-byte to 4-byte conversion of data on the fly.   Either way, there is a copy of data from host to device, but this method doesn't require 4 byte per pixel input data.

Here is code demonstrating both options:

```
//nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t19 glad/src/glad.c t19.cu -lGL -lGLU -I./glad/include -lglfw -std=c++11 -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <cudaGL.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


/** Macro for checking if CUDA has problems */
#define cudaCheckError() { \
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError(); \
    if(err != cudaSuccess) { \
      printf("Cuda error: %s:%d: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err)); \
      exit(1); \
    } \
  }


/*Window dimensions*/
//const int windowWidth = 1280, windowHeight = 720;
/*Window address*/
GLFWwindow* currentGLFWWindow = 0;


/**
 * A simple image processing kernel that copies the inverted data from the input surface to the output surface.
 */
__global__ void kernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t input, cudaSurfaceObject_t output, int width, int height, uint8_t *data) {

    //Get the pixel index
    unsigned int xPx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    unsigned int yPx = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;


    //Don't do any computation if this thread is outside of the surface bounds.
    if (xPx >= width || yPx >= height) return;

    //Copy the contents of input to output.
#ifdef USE_1
    uchar4 pixel = { 255,128,0,255 };
    //Read a pixel from the input. Disable to default to the flat orange color above
    surf2Dread<uchar4>(&pixel, input, xPx * sizeof(uchar4), yPx, cudaBoundaryModeClamp);

#else
    uchar4 pixel;
    pixel.x = data[(xPx+yPx*width)*3 + 0];
    pixel.y = data[(xPx+yPx*width)*3 + 1];
    pixel.z = data[(xPx+yPx*width)*3 + 2];
    pixel.w = 255;
    surf2Dwrite(pixel, input, xPx * sizeof(uchar4), yPx);
#endif
    //Invert the color
    pixel.x = ~pixel.x;
    pixel.y = ~pixel.y;
    pixel.z = ~pixel.z;
    //Write the new pixel color to the 
    surf2Dwrite(pixel, output, xPx * sizeof(uchar4), yPx);
}

class Processor {
public:
    void setInput( uint8_t* const data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight);
    void processData(uint8_t *data, uint8_t *d_data);
    GLuint getInputTexture();
    GLuint getOutputTexture();
    void writeOutputTo(uint8_t* destination);
private:
    /**
    * @brief True if the textures and surfaces are initialized.
    *
    * Prevents memory leaks
    */
    bool surfacesInitialized = false;
    /**
     * @brief The width and height of a texture/surface pair.
     *
     */
    struct ImgDim { int width, height; };
    /**
     * @brief Creates a CUDA surface object, CUDA resource, and OpenGL texture from some data.
     */
    void createTextureSurfacePair(const ImgDim& dimensions, uint8_t* const data, GLuint& textureOut, cudaGraphicsResource_t& graphicsResourceOut, cudaSurfaceObject_t& surfaceOut);
    /**
     * @brief Destroys every CUDA surface object, CUDA resource, and OpenGL texture created by this instance.
     */
    void destroyEverything();
    /**
     * @brief The dimensions of an image and its corresponding texture.
     *
     */
    ImgDim imageInputDimensions, imageOutputDimensions;
    /**
     * @brief A CUDA surface that can be read to, written from, or synchronized with a Mat or
     * OpenGL texture
     *
     */
    cudaSurfaceObject_t d_imageInputTexture = 0, d_imageOutputTexture = 0;
    /**
     * @brief A CUDA resource that's bound to an array in CUDA memory
     */
    cudaGraphicsResource_t d_imageInputGraphicsResource, d_imageOutputGraphicsResource;
    /**
     * @brief A renderable OpenGL texture that is synchronized with the CUDA data
     * @see d_imageInputTexture, d_imageOutputTexture
     */
    GLuint imageInputTexture = 0, imageOutputTexture = 0;
    /** Returns true if nothing can be rendered */
    bool empty() { return imageInputTexture == 0; }

};


void Processor::setInput(uint8_t* const data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
{


    //Same-size images don't need texture regeneration, so skip that.
    if (imageHeight == imageInputDimensions.height && imageWidth == imageInputDimensions.width) {


        /*
        Possible shortcut: we know the input is the same size as the texture and CUDA surface object.
        So instead of destroying the surface and texture, why not just overwrite them?

        That's what I try to do in the following block, but because "data" is BGR and the texture
        is RGBA, the channels get all messed up.
        */

        //Use the input surface's CUDAResourceDesc to gain access to the surface data array
#ifdef USE_1
    struct cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
        memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
        cudaGetSurfaceObjectResourceDesc(&resDesc, d_imageInputTexture);
        cudaCheckError();
        uint8_t *data4 = new uint8_t[imageInputDimensions.width*imageInputDimensions.height*4];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageInputDimensions.width*imageInputDimensions.height; i++){
        data4[i*4+0] = data[i*3+0];
        data4[i*4+1] = data[i*3+1];
        data4[i*4+2] = data[i*3+2];
        data4[i*4+3] = 255;}
        //Copy the data from the input array to the surface
//        cudaMemcpyToArray(resDesc.res.array.array, 0, 0, data, imageInputDimensions.width * imageInputDimensions.height * 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy2DToArray(resDesc.res.array.array, 0, 0, data4, imageInputDimensions.width*4, imageInputDimensions.width*4, imageInputDimensions.height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckError();
        delete[] data4;
#endif
        //Set status flags
        surfacesInitialized = true;

        return;
    }


    //Clear everything that originally existed in the texture/surface
    destroyEverything();

    //Get the size of the image and place it here.
    imageInputDimensions.width = imageWidth;
    imageInputDimensions.height = imageHeight;
    imageOutputDimensions.width = imageWidth;
    imageOutputDimensions.height = imageHeight;

    //Create the input surface/texture pair
    createTextureSurfacePair(imageInputDimensions, data, imageInputTexture, d_imageInputGraphicsResource, d_imageInputTexture);

    //Create the output surface/texture pair
    uint8_t* outData = new uint8_t[imageOutputDimensions.width * imageOutputDimensions.height * 3];
    createTextureSurfacePair(imageOutputDimensions, outData, imageOutputTexture, d_imageOutputGraphicsResource, d_imageOutputTexture);
    delete outData;

    //Set status flags
    surfacesInitialized = true;
}

void Processor::processData(uint8_t *data, uint8_t *d_data)
{
    const int threadsPerBlock = 128;

    //Call the algorithm

    //Set the number of blocks to call the kernel with.
    dim3 blocks((unsigned int)ceil((float)imageInputDimensions.width / threadsPerBlock), imageInputDimensions.height);
#ifndef USE_1
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, imageInputDimensions.width*imageInputDimensions.height*3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
#endif
    kernel <<<blocks, threadsPerBlock >>> (d_imageInputTexture, d_imageOutputTexture, imageInputDimensions.width, imageInputDimensions.height, d_data);

    //Sync the surface with the texture
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckError();
}

GLuint Processor::getInputTexture()
{
    return imageInputTexture;
}

GLuint Processor::getOutputTexture()
{
    return imageOutputTexture;
}

void Processor::writeOutputTo(uint8_t* destination)
{
    //Haven't figured this out yet
}

void Processor::createTextureSurfacePair(const Processor::ImgDim& dimensions, uint8_t* const data, GLuint& textureOut, cudaGraphicsResource_t& graphicsResourceOut, cudaSurfaceObject_t& surfaceOut) {

    // Create the OpenGL texture that will be displayed with GLAD and GLFW
    glGenTextures(1, &textureOut);
    // Bind to our texture handle
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureOut);
    // Set texture interpolation methods for minification and magnification
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    // Set texture clamping method
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    // Create the texture and its attributes
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,     // Type of texture
        0,                // Pyramid level (for mip-mapping) - 0 is the top level
        GL_RGBA,          // Internal color format to convert to
        dimensions.width,            // Image width  i.e. 640 for Kinect in standard mode
        dimensions.height,           // Image height i.e. 480 for Kinect in standard mode
        0,                // Border width in pixels (can either be 1 or 0)
        GL_BGR,          // Input image format (i.e. GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, GL_BGR etc.)
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // Image data type.
        data);            // The actual image data itself
    //Note that the type of this texture is an RGBA UNSIGNED_BYTE type. When CUDA surfaces
    //are synchronized with OpenGL textures, the surfaces will be of the same type.
    //They won't know or care about their data types though, for they are all just byte arrays
    //at heart. So be careful to ensure that any CUDA kernel that handles a CUDA surface
    //uses it as an appropriate type. You will see that the update_surface kernel (defined 
    //above) treats each pixel as four unsigned bytes along the X-axis: one for red, green, blue,
    //and alpha respectively.

    //Create the CUDA array and texture reference
    cudaArray* bitmap_d;
    //Register the GL texture with the CUDA graphics library. A new cudaGraphicsResource is created, and its address is placed in cudaTextureID.
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1g80d12187ae7590807c7676697d9fe03d
    cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&graphicsResourceOut, textureOut, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone);
    cudaCheckError();
    //Map graphics resources for access by CUDA.
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1gad8fbe74d02adefb8e7efb4971ee6322
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &graphicsResourceOut, 0);
    cudaCheckError();
    //Get the location of the array of pixels that was mapped by the previous function and place that address in bitmap_d
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1g0dd6b5f024dfdcff5c28a08ef9958031
    cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&bitmap_d, graphicsResourceOut, 0, 0);
    cudaCheckError();
    //Create a CUDA resource descriptor. This is used to get and set attributes of CUDA resources.
    //This one will tell CUDA how we want the bitmap_surface to be configured.
    //Documentation for the struct: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaResourceDesc.html#structcudaResourceDesc
    struct cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
    //Clear it with 0s so that some flags aren't arbitrarily left at 1s
    memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
    //Set the resource type to be an array for convenient processing in the CUDA kernel.
    //List of resTypes: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g067b774c0e639817a00a972c8e2c203c
    resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    //Bind the new descriptor with the bitmap created earlier.
    resDesc.res.array.array = bitmap_d;
    //Create a new CUDA surface ID reference.
    //This is really just an unsigned long long.
    //Docuentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1gbe57cf2ccbe7f9d696f18808dd634c0a
    surfaceOut = 0;
    //Create the surface with the given description. That surface ID is placed in bitmap_surface.
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT_1g958899474ab2c5f40d233b524d6c5a01
    cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&surfaceOut, &resDesc);
    cudaCheckError();
}

void Processor::destroyEverything()
{
    if (surfacesInitialized) {

        //Input image CUDA surface
        cudaDestroySurfaceObject(d_imageInputTexture);
        cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &d_imageInputGraphicsResource);
        cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(d_imageInputGraphicsResource);
        d_imageInputTexture = 0;

        //Output image CUDA surface
        cudaDestroySurfaceObject(d_imageOutputTexture);
        cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &d_imageOutputGraphicsResource);
        cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(d_imageOutputGraphicsResource);
        d_imageOutputTexture = 0;

        //Input image GL texture
        glDeleteTextures(1, &imageInputTexture);
        imageInputTexture = 0;

        //Output image GL texture
        glDeleteTextures(1, &imageOutputTexture);
        imageOutputTexture = 0;

        surfacesInitialized = false;
    }
}


/** A way to initialize OpenGL with GLFW and GLAD */
void initGL(int windowWidth, int windowHeight) {

    // Setup window
    if (!glfwInit())
        return;

    // Decide GL+GLSL versions
#if __APPLE__
    // GL 3.2 + GLSL 150
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 150";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // Required on Mac
#else
    // GL 3.0 + GLSL 130
    //const char* glsl_version = "#version 130";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // 3.0+ only
#endif

    // Create window with graphics context
    currentGLFWWindow = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Output image (OpenGL + GLFW)", NULL, NULL);
    if (currentGLFWWindow == NULL)
        return;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(currentGLFWWindow);
    glfwSwapInterval(3); // Enable vsync

    if (!gladLoadGL()) {
        // GLAD failed
        printf( "GLAD failed to initialize :(" );
        return;
    }

    //Change GL settings
    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); // use a screen size of WIDTH x HEIGHT

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);     // Make a simple 2D projection on the entire window
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);    // Set the matrix mode to object modeling

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the window
}

/** Renders the textures on the GLFW window and requests GLFW to update */
void showTextures(GLuint top, GLuint bottom, int windowWidth, int windowHeight) {
    // Clear color and depth buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // Operate on model-view matrix

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, top);
    /* Draw top quad */
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, windowHeight/2);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(windowWidth, 0);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    /* Draw bottom quad */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bottom);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, windowHeight / 2);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, windowHeight);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glfwSwapBuffers(currentGLFWWindow);
    glfwPollEvents();
}


int main() {
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

//    initGL();

    std::string filename = "./lena.pgm";

    Mat image;
    image = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }
    int windoww = 1280;
    int windowh = 720;
    initGL(windoww,windowh);
 
    uint8_t *d_data;
    cudaMalloc(&d_data, image.cols*image.rows*3);
    Processor p;
    for (int i = 0; i < image.cols; i++)
    {
        image.data[i*3+0] = 0;
        image.data[i*3+1] = 0;
        image.data[i*3+2] = 0;
        //Process the image here
        p.setInput(image.data, image.cols, image.rows);
        p.processData(image.data, d_data);
        showTextures(p.getInputTexture(), p.getOutputTexture(), windoww, windowh);
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. The compilation command is given in the comment in the first line
2. I created a "video" of sorts using a single image.  The "video" will show the image with a black or white line moving horizontally from left to right in the top pixel row of the image.  The input image is `lena.pgm` which can be found in the CUDA samples (for example, at `/usr/local/cuda-10.1/samples/3_Imaging/SobelFilter/data/lena.pgm`).
3. It looks to me like you are "sharing" resources between OpenGL and CUDA.  This doesn't look like the right map/unmap sequence to me, but it seems to be working, and it doesn't seem to be the focus of your question.  I haven't spent any time investigating.  I may have missed something.
4. I'm not suggesting this code is defect free or suitable for any particular purpose.  It is mostly your code.  I've modified it slightly to demonstrate some ideas described in the text.
5. There shouldn't be any visual difference in the output whether you compile with `-DUSE_1` or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is an useful feature that came across first in (https://www.3dgep.com/opengl-interoperability-with-cuda/), and I have improved upon it to use latest CUDA APIs and flow. You can refer to these 2 functions in cudammf.

https://github.com/prabindh/cudammf/blob/5f93358784fcbaae7eea0850424c59d2ed057dab/cuda_postproces.cu#L119

https://github.com/prabindh/cudammf/blob/5f93358784fcbaae7eea0850424c59d2ed057dab/decoder3.cpp#L507

Basic working is as below:

1. Create a regular GL texture (GLTextureId). Map it for CUDA access, via `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage`
2. Do some CUDA processing, and result is in a CUDA buffer
3. USe `cudaMemcpyToArray` to transfer between the above 2 device memories

If your output is coming from a Nvidia codec output, you should also refer to the `AppDecGL` sample in the Nvidia Video SDK (https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk).